# How to play the port audio in basic raw

Tags: c, gstreamer

How can i do raw send and raw receive ? This is not working, i cant play what i sended:

```
Send: $ gst-launch -v autoaudiosrc ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 auto-multicast=true port=4444

Recv/play:
[root@example ~]# gst-launch udpsrc multicast-group=127.0.0.1 port=4444 ! autoaudiosink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoAudioSink:autoaudiosink0/GstPulseSink:autoaudiosink0-actual-sink-pulse: The stream is in the wrong format.
Additional debug info:
gstbaseaudiosink.c(866): gst_base_audio_sink_preroll (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoAudioSink:autoaudiosink0/GstPulseSink:autoaudiosink0-actual-sink-pulse:
sink not negotiated.
Execution ended after 16110169 ns.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
[root@example ~]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify capabilities for source. This is what actually `ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioConvert:audioconvert0: not negotiated` means.
(Use `-v` flag on gst-launch to see more details on errors).

So, the solution is:

```
$ gst-launch -v udpsrc multicast-group=127.0.0.1 port=4444 \
    ! audio/x-raw-int, endianness=1234, signed=true, width=16, depth=16, rate=44100, channels=2 \
    ! autoaudiosink
```

Actually, I just copied capabilities from the verbose output of the sending gst-launch.

Comment: That worked, you are genius expert..... but this is not working what can be the issue ? Send (works):gst-launch -v pulsesrc ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! oggmux ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 auto-multicast=true port=4444

Recv (same like hte above one i dont hear anything): gst-launch -v udpsrc multicast-group=127.0.0.1 port=4444 \
    ! audio/x-raw-int, endianness=1234, signed=true, width=16, depth=16, rate=44100, channels=2 \
    ! autoaudiosink

Comment: @Stackfan, you can't hear anything because you sending vorbis-compressed stream, but trying to play x-raw-int. you need to fix capabilities and use `oggdemux ! vorbisdec` afterwards. Btw, you can describe your task and try to contact me via jorpic@gmai.com

Comment: Send (works): gst-launch -v pulsesrc ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! oggmux ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 auto-multicast=true port=4444, and reading the -v

Comment: @max taldykin: sure i will, but very strange i followed the "-v" and modified like here, but didnt worked ! ex: https://gist.github.com/736438

Comment: @Stackfan, actually you get application/ogg at the udpsrc, because oggmux outputs it

Comment: Strange decode does not work ? # gst-launch -v udpsrc multicast-group=127.0.0.1 port=4444 ! audio/x-raw-int, endianness=1234, signed=true, width=32, rate=44100, channels=1 ! audioconvert ! vorbisdec ! oggmux ! autoaudiosink
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link audioconvert0 to vorbisdec0

Comment: This also didnt works. ex: gst-launch -v udpsrc multicast-group=127.0.0.1 port=4444 ! oggdemux ! vorbisdec ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink

Comment: According to mannual i tried but it gives error: http://www.gstreamer.net/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-vorbisdec.html